# Airflow - are UTC time and DAG time the same?

Tags: airflow

I am quite confused about time concept in airflow. As far as I know, there are at least 5 different time concept in airflow:

1. UTC time in web UI
2. `Execution` time, e.g. `start_date`, in DAG file
3. `RUN` time.
4. time saved in database
5. system time

Could anyone explain which are the same and which are different?

Answer (score 0):

The UTC time in the Web UI(1) is the system time (5) being presented.

The run time (3) shows when a task was actually run in UTC and this is the time saved in the database (4) as it corresponds to when a certain task was actually ran in a DAG.

The start_date should be a static non-changing date as it corresponds to when the DAG was first started and should be backfilled if certain parameters like `catchup` or `depends_on_past` is set to `true`.

So 5 and 1 are the same, 3 and 4 are the same, and 5 is it's own entity of time.